# Request object properties are empty, yet request is made

Tags: php, silex, bolt-cms

Creating a bolt extension and trying to access request variables. I have set up an endpoint `GET /api/session`, which for now should just return the request:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->app->get("/api/session", array($this, 'getSession'))
              ->bind('getSession');
}

public function getSession(Request $request)
{
    $response = $this->app->json(array('request' => $request));
    return $response;
}
```

But the response is:

```
"request": {
    "attributes": { },
    "request": { },
    "query": { },
    "server": { },
    "files": { },
    "cookies": { },
    "headers": { }
}
```

There were headers sent, and I've tested it with queries too, but nothing is returned in the response. How do I get the full response? Full code is available at: https://github.com/babaggeii/bolt-extension-restapi